# How to implement audit trail in asp.net mvc5 and entity-framework in code first, using trackerenableddbcontext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, code-first

I am working on an MVC5 application using Entity framework and code first migration, I want to implement audit trail. I have found a NuGet package called trackerenableddbcontext that seems easy to use. however, I did install the package, and did the following code but still nothing is being added to the audit table.

I have implemented the inherited from the Tracker Context as shown in the code

```
DBContext class
public class SIContext : TrackerContext //DbContext
{
    public SIContext()
        : base("name=SIConnectionString")
    {
    }


    public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MenuPermission> MenuPermissions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategorys { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tax> Taxs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductStock> ProductStocks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PaymentMode> PaymentModes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InvoiceItems> InvoiceItemss { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InvoiceFormat> InvoiceFormats { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InventoryType> InventoryTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<LedgerAccount> LedgerAccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DuePayment> DuePayments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DeliveryNote> DeliveryNotes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GRV> GRVs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Artisans> Artisans { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<JobCard> JobCards { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InternalRequisitionForm> InternalRequisitionForms { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<JobRequisition> JobRequisitions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Stores> Stores { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ListItems> listitem { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<JobCardServices> JobCardServices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<JobCardMaterials> JobCardMaterials { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<JobRequisitionMaterials> JobRequisitionMaterials { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<JobRequisitionServices> JobRequisitionServices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GRVMaterials> GRVMaterials { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Quotation> Quotations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<QuotationItems> QuotationItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DNoteMaterial> DNoteMaterials { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InvoiceMaterials> InvoiceMaterial { get; set; }






    //
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.RoleMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.UserMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.MenuMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.MenuPermissionMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.ProductCategoryMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.ProductMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.TaxMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.ProductStockMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.PaymentModeMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.SaleMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.InvoiceItemsMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.SettingMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.InvoiceFormatMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.InventoryTypeMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.PurchaseMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.TransactionMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.InvoiceMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.LedgerAccountMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.WarehouseMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.DuePaymentMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.ExpenseMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShopMate.Maping.InternalRequisitionFormMap());



        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


}
```

Table i want to track

```
[TrackChanges]
public class Product
{
    [DisplayName("S.No")] 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)] 
    [DisplayName("Name")] 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Category")] 
    public int? ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory_ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)] 
    [DisplayName("Bar Code")] 
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Purchase Price")] 
    public Decimal PurchasePrice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Sale Price")] 
    public Decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Product Image")] 
    public string ProductImage { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Added By")] 
    public Nullable<int> AddedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Date Added")] 
    public Nullable<DateTime> DateAdded { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Modified By")] 
    public Nullable<int> ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Date Modied")] 
    public Nullable<DateTime> DateModied { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Is Active")] 
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Stock Alert")] 
    public int StockAlert { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Tax")] 
    public Nullable<int> TaxId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Warehouse")] 
    public int WarehouseId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Discount")]
    public Nullable<Decimal> Discount { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Remaining Quantity")]
    public Nullable<Decimal> RemainingQuantity { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Remaining Amount")]
    public Nullable<Decimal> RemainingAmount { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [DisplayName("HSN")]
    public string HSN { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductStock> ProductStock_ProductIds { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sale> Sale_ProductIds { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceItems> InvoiceItems_ProductIds { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchase_ProductIds { get; set; }
}}
```

Controler Function

```
[HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product ObjProduct, HttpPostedFileBase ProductImage, string HideImage1)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Env.GetUserInfo("userid"));
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (ProductImage != null)
                {
                    var fileName = MicrosoftHelper.MSHelper.StarkFileUploaderCSharp(ProductImage, Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"));
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ObjProduct.ProductImage = fileName;
                }
                else
                {
                    ObjProduct.ProductImage = HideImage1;
                }


                db.Entry(ObjProduct).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges(userId);

                sb.Append("Sumitted");
                return Content(sb.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var key in this.ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
                {
                    foreach (var err in this.ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors)
                    {
                        sb.Append(err.ErrorMessage + "<br/>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sb.Append("Error :" + ex.Message);
        }


        return Content(sb.ToString());

    }
```

I want it  save the changes to the database, in the audidlog, and auditlogdetails tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using attaching entity into DBContext you need to add `GlobalTrackingConfig.DisconnectedContext = true;` on application startup.

[Here is documentation](https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext/wiki/0.-Techniques#2-manually-attaching-entities)